# Image preview only in desired folder

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, I would like to know how to preview images only in the folders I need, when I change the view of the files it affects all the folders in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with Files (aka nautilus), the default file manager of Ubuntu, and likely not with most file manager around. While some file managers, such as nemo, remember the view on a per folder basis (i.e. folder view/list view/compact view, ...), also in these file managers, the setting to show preview images instead of icons will apply to any file manager window (and folder).